# Cannot build DLL with <random> library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a DLL project that I am working in and I've tried using the `<random>` header for the random number generation.

**My Tools:** Visual Studio 2019 C++ MSVC

When ever I try to build the following slightly modified code [Example code from Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/random?view=vs-2019):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int getRandNum()
{
    std::random_device rd;   // non-deterministic generator
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());  // to seed mersenne twister.
                             // replace the call to rd() with a
                             // constant value to get repeatable
                             // results.
    return gen();
}
```

I get these errors:

[image]

After unsuccessful research I've decided to quickly make a new DLL project and use this same function in it, same problem. I then created a console project and tested the function with the header and it all worked fine.

I am not sure what I am missing, maybe a configuration problem?

Comment: What version of C++ have you configured your project for?

Comment: @idmean C++17 (default)

Comment: Are these all errors you are seeing? Do you have a precompilation header configured?

Comment: Only "stdafx.h". I have managed to get it to work, but not how I want it to work. I was using the <random> library in another source file (calling the respective function from main source file) and it didn't work. I am now using it in the "main" source file where the DllMain() function is and it's working and creating my values.

Comment: Glad you got it working. In my experience VS can issue strange errors if you do not include the precompilation header, so that could have been the issue.